# Programatically selection destination nodes for moveTo block

Tags: java, anylogic

I am working on an model where a plane must move to a gate.
The plane has its destination gate set as its parameter.

When I try to programmatically assign the gate to the `moveTo`'s `self.DEST_NODE`, I get what I think is a type error.

I'm quite new to Java, and think the problem might be in the code.

Additional information: when I add no program but simply fill the node field with `p_Gate1` then the program works.

I am very interested in converting the `PointNode` type to a `moveTo.Destination` type or something similar.

Ps. Thanks to Benjamin Schumann, I can now select between two options, but I would like all five gates enabled. (`agent.gate==1 ? p_Gate1 : p_Gate2`)

Please see attached screenshot. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot with errors]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same code with nested conditions for 5 gate options as follows:

```
agent.gate==1 ? p_Gate1 : agent.gate==2 ? p_Gate2 : agent.gate==3 ? p_Gate3 : agent.gate==4 ? p_Gate4 : p_Gate5
```